# ruby variable scoping across classes

Tags: ruby, class, imap, scoping

RuNubie here. I've got a class `Login` that logs into gmail using the `net/IMAP` library. What is happening is that I create a new instance of that class, such as:

```
a = Login.new("username", "gmail.com", "passw")
```

Then, I'm working on other classes that will do some "stuff" with the mailbox. The problem is that the `@imap` variable I've defined in Login seems to have disappeared (due to scoping I assume).

This is how `@imap` is declared in Login class: 
`@imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com',993,true,nil,false)`

So this:

```
  @today = Date.today
  @received_today = imap.search(["SINCE", @today.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")]).count.to_s
```

...returns an error. These are the two errors I've gotten while playing around with this. The first one is when I use `imap`, the second one is when I try `@imap`:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `imap' for #<Object:0x10718d2a8>
NoMethodError: undefined method `search' for nil:NilClass
```

What are the best practices for dealing with a situation like this? Is the only solution to define my methods that do "stuff" in the same class where I'm creating the new instance of Net::IMAP? Is declaring `@imap` as a global variable `$imap` a bad practice? So confused, I bet the answer is very simple and obvious too, but I'm just not seeing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
@received_today = imap.search(["SINCE", @today.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")]).count.to_s
```

won't work because, well, there is no `imap` in scope at that point and so you get a NameError. When you try it like this:

```
@received_today = @imap.search(["SINCE", @today.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")]).count.to_s
```

You get a NoMethodError because instance variables, such as `@imap`, are automatically created at first use and initialized as `nil`. Your real `@imap` is in another object so you can't refer to it as `@imap` anywhere else.

I think you want a structure more like this:

```
class User
    def imap
        if(!@imap)
            @imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, true, nil, false)
            # and presumably an @imap.authenticate too...
        end
        @imap
    end
end

class OtherOne
    def some_method(user)
        @today = Date.today
        @received_today = user.imap.search(["SINCE", @today.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")]).count.to_s
    end
end
```

Keep your `Net::IMAP` localized inside your User and let other objects use it by providing a simple accessor method.

Oh and that global `$imap` idea, I'll just pretend I didn't see that as globals are almost always a really bad idea.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense, so basically the instance of class User is passed as an argument to some_method of class OtherOne, it seems like. I am concerned that this way every time another class calls class User, Net::IMAP logs in and authenticates a mailbox. Seems like it might get slow if many other classes/methods keep trying to "do stuff" to the mailbox and have to log in each time. It sounds like, based on your answer, that there's no way to just log in with net/IMAP and keep it open.

Comment: @krapdagn: `Net::IMAP.new` will only be called once per user, after that `imap` just returns the existing `@imap`. You might want some logic to reconnect if `@imap` gets disconnected though.

Answer (score 1):

a shorter way to define the imap variable in the User class, which is pretty much the same as what mu posted:

```
class User
   def imap
      @imap ||= Net::IMAP.new...
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I love how Ruby has multiple ways to solve problems. Great to learn new things like the ||=